# How to send an outlook mailitem using specific email address?

Tags: c#, outlook

Hi does anyone know how to send or reply to an outlook mailitem using a specific string of email address?

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

my outlook email address is:

```
string email = "myOutlookEmailAddress@company.com";
```

now instead of my outlook email address, i want to use (email address from a specific mailbox on my outlook):

```
string email = "otherEmailAddress@company.com";
```

I already tried using this:

```
Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts; 
foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts) 
{ 
    // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
    if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress) 
    { 
        return account; 
    } 
}
```

but its only looking up for the accounts on what is in my outlook application.

Comment: So you want to send a message from an account that is not configured within outlook?

Comment: @YacoubMassad sorry i just edited my question.

Comment: So did you find the right `Account`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad no because the email address of that mailbox is not in the account settings :( do you know atleast how to access the email address of that mailbox?

Comment: You can't do this, without the primary account being given delegate rights to the other account. Talk to a SMTP server instead.

Comment: What has this to do with ASP.NET?

Comment: @stuartd do you mean i should use smtpclient instead?? if yes, i already done that but i am having a problem on sending the body of the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are sending through Exchange on behalf of another mailbox, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property (assuming you have sufficient privileges)
2. If you are sending through a particular SMTP account, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property.
3. If you need to send as an arbitrary SMTP user, see [this example](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14) on my website - you will essentially need to set the "From" named MAPI property in the `PS_INTERNET_HEADERS` namespace. Note that not all SMTP servers will let you do that - Exchange for one will not let you spoof the sender.
4. If you want to send as one of the alias (proxy) SMTP addresses belonging to a particular Exchange mailbox, you will need to send through SMTP - sending through OOM or MAPI  will always send with the default SMTP address of the mailbox. For an end user, you can configure a dummy POP3/SMTP account or use a product like [Proxy Manager](http://www.dimastr.com/proxyman/) (I am its author). See [MSOutlook.info](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/send-mail-from-additional-exchange-address-or-alias) for more information.